# getting last month visits total

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I' m trying to get how many visit to customer sells rep. did last month I create this sql to give me visit for customer in currents but I need to be apple t to get last month  total Visits
[image]

```
declare @FromDate date, @ToDate date
set @FromDate = '11/01/2012'
set @ToDate = '11/30/2012'

SELECT COUNT(VisitTracking.customerID) AS #VISIT
FROM VisitTracking INNER JOIN Customers 
   ON VisitTracking.customerID = Customers.customerID  INNER JOIN Customer_Company 
   ON Customers.customerID = Customer_Company.customerID INNER JOIN Company 
   ON Customer_Company.companyID = Company.companyID
 WHERE VisitTracking.DateVisited  BETWEEN 
          DATEADD(m, datediff(DD, 0, @FromDate)-1, 0)  AND  
          DATEADD(M, datediff(month, 0, @ToDate)-1, 0) 
GO 

 SELECT     COUNT(VisitTracking.customerID) AS #VISIT
    FROM         VisitTracking 
    WHERE VisitTracking.DateVisited  BETWEEN DATEADD(m, datediff(DD, 0, @FromDate)-1, 0)  AND DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,@ToDate),0))
```

Comment: What is the problem with your current query?

Comment: I need to get how many visit happen last month

Comment: What is the problem? Parsing DateTimes or doesn't the query work at all?

Comment: the have problem Parsing DateTime to last month this is my last sql

Comment: How do you call this Stored Procedure from your C# code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this code

```
declare @FromDate date
,@ToDate date
set @FromDate = '11/01/2012'
set @ToDate = '11/30/2012'

SELECT     COUNT(VisitTracking.customerID) AS #VISIT
FROM         VisitTracking 
WHERE VisitTracking.DateVisited  BETWEEN DATEADD(m, datediff(MM, 0, @FromDate)-1, 0)  and  DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,@ToDate),0))
```

Answer (score 0):

mmmmm, may be you can use the session proprieties,,, but use it as you can reach its advantage,

something like:

Application start--->

> Application.add("UserCount",0);

Session Start--->

> int UserCount=int.parse(Appplication.get("UserCount").tostring());
>   UserCount++; Application.set("UserCount",UserCount);

Comment: this is not for website visit. it's for sell rep when he visit custome

Comment: OK, you can make a table for months,, which have a computed column that  use the count function with a condition of month interval !

Comment: I thin I figure out what is the problem  DATEADD(month, datediff(MONTH, 0, @ToDate)-1, 0) result is '2012-10-01 00:00:00.000' and I want to to be '2012-10-31 00:00:00.000'